# How to change the value of a prop of Sub Component passed as a column to React Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, react-state, react-state-management

I am using **[React Table](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table)** Library in Web Application.

I am passing a component as a column to the table. Columns and data for the table looks like below.

```
  columns = [
    {
      Header: "Name",
      accessor: "name"
    },
    {
      Header: "Action",
      accessor: "action"
    }
  ];

  sampleData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Product one",
      action: (
        <TestComponent
          id={1}
          inProgress={false}
          onClickHandler={id => this.onClickHandler(id)}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Product two",
      action: (
        <TestComponent
          id={2}
          inProgress={false}
          onClickHandler={id => this.onClickHandler(id)}
        />
      )
    }
  ];
```

My **`TestComponent`** Looks like below.

```
const TestComponent = ({ id, inProgress, onClickHandler }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {inProgress ? (
        <p>In Progress </p>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => onClickHandler(id)}>click me</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

What my purpose is, When user click on **`click me`** button it needs to call a **`Backend API`**. At that time **`inProgress`** prop need to be **`true`** and it should pass to the table and need text as In Progress until API call completed.

I could be able to do it changing **`state`** as below.

```
  onClickHandler(id) {
    const newData = this.sampleData.map(data => {
      if (data.id === id) {
        return {
          ...data,
          action: (
            <TestComponent
              id={1}
              inProgress={true}
              onClickHandler={id => this.onClickHandler(id)}
            />
          )
        };
      }
      return data;
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData });

    // Here I Call the Backend API and after complete that need to show the click me button again.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ data: this.sampleData });
    }, 3000);
  }
```

I could be able to achieve what I need But I am not satisfied the way I am changing the **`state`**. I need to know is there a better way of doing this without changing **`state`** like this.

**You can use this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-table-demo-2rbiba?file=index.js) Link for giving me a better solution. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `inProgress` prop to `TestComponent`, you could maintain a local state in the `TestComponent` that is used to determine whether to show progress text or a button and only pass the `id` and `onClickHanlder` props to `TestComponent`.

When button is clicked in `TestComponent`, you could set the the local state of `TestComponent` to show the progress text and then call the `onClickHandler` function passed as prop, passing in the `id` prop and a callback function as arguments. This callback function will be called when API request is completed. This callback function is defined inside `TestComponent` and only toggles the local state of the `TestComponent` to hide the progress text and show the button again.

Change your `TestComponent` to as shown below:

```
const TestComponent = ({ id, onClickHandler }) => {
  const [showProgress, setShowProgress] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleShowProgress = () => {
    setShowProgress(showProgress => !showProgress);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowProgress(true);
    onClickHandler(id, toggleShowProgress);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {showProgress ? (
        <p>In Progress </p>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

i have used `useState` hook to maintain local state of the `TestComponent` as it is a functional component but you could use the same logic in a class component as well.

Change the `TestComponent` in `sampleData` array to only be passed two props, `id` and `onClickHandler`.

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "Product one",
   action: <TestComponent id={1} onClickHandler={this.onClickHandler} />
 }
```

and change `onClickHandler` method in `App` component to:

```
onClickHandler(id, callback) {
   // make the api request, call 'callback' function when request is completed
    setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, 3000);
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit crazy-fire-fvlhm]

Alternatively, you could make `onClickHandler` function in `App` component to return a `Promise` that is fulfilled when API request completes. This way you don't have to pass a callback function from `TestComponent` to `onClickHandler` method in `App` component.

Change `onClickHandler` method to:

```
onClickHandler(id) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
   });
}
```

and change `TestComponent` to:

```
const TestComponent = ({ id, onClickHandler }) => {
  const [showProgress, setShowProgress] = useState(false);

  const toggleShowProgress = () => {
    setShowProgress(showProgress => !showProgress);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowProgress(true);

    onClickHandler(id)
      .then(toggleShowProgress)
      .catch(error => {
        toggleShowProgress();
        // handle the error
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {showProgress ? (
        <p>In Progress </p>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>click me</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Demo

[image: Edit practical-sinoussi-r92qj]

Comment: thanks a lot for the great answer. It helps a lot. have a nice day.